# PS2 DDR pad -> USB adapter -> Bionic: jstest works, but nothing else (antimicro, qjoypad)

Tags: drivers, usb, gamepad

I have an old Konami Dance pad for PS2, and I have the USB adapter to plug it into my machine. I ran `jstest /dev/input/js0` and it sees my pad just fine. I can press any button and see it react. This means I should be able to use my pad just fine.

However, if I run Antimicro, it'll see the pad but won't react when I press anything. Same with qjoypad. And when I test input in Stepmania, it doesn't see anything.

So why the disconnect from jstest to anything else? I ran `modprobe joydev` and `sudo modprobe analog` but this didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the system's logs? Do something like `sudo journalctl  --since="-5  minutes"`.

Comment: Can you update your question with the vendor ID and product ID for the USB PS2 adapter? Also, see if it works with `evtest`.